# calculate inner angles of a polygon

Tags: opencv

I have the following array of arrays:

```
[[[623 284]]

 [[526 256]]

 [[532 189]]

 [[504 166]]

 [[323 175]]

 [[276 219]]

 [[119 221]]

 [[  1 272]]

 [[  0 473]]

 [[615 479]]]
```

These are my points (coordinates) of polygon. What I need to do, is to iterate through this array, taking each point for calculating every inner angle in polygon. I have this function for calculating angle between 3 points: `getAngle((px1, py1), (px2, py2), (px3, py3))`.
Basically I want to put this function in some loop which will take points repectively, like:

```
getAngle((623, 284), (526, 256), (532, 189)),
getAngle((526, 256), (532, 189), (504, 166)),
getAngle((532, 189), (504, 166), (323, 175)),
```

and so on until the end...
Which loop it suppose to be and how to implement it?

Comment: rather than iterate, you might try to write a sort-of recursive function which shifts a kind of frame 3-node down the line while calculating the current value with the three active node

Comment: that looks like a *numpy array*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this:

```
lst = [[[623,284]] , [[526, 256]] , [[532, 189]]]

tuple(map((lambda x : tuple(x[0])), lst))
```

output:

```
((623, 284), (526, 256), (532, 189))
```

**EDIT** as your comment:

```
lst = [[[623,284]], [[526, 256]], [[532, 189]], [[504, 166]], [[323, 175]], [[276, 219]], [[119, 221]], [[  1, 272]], [[  0, 473]] , [[615, 479]]]


for l in range(0,len(lst)-2):
    f , s , t = (tuple(map((lambda x : tuple(x[0])), lst[l:l+3])))
    getAngle(f , s, t)
```

Comment: I need to call a function inside the foor loop, not making a tuple from array.

Comment: it gives me error that getAngle function need 3 arguments, but got only one

Comment: @user16731999 try now, i add one line

Comment: @user16731999, OK, wait on second, i understand

Comment: first of all I edited your code as `for l in range(0,len(lst)-2,3):` because it didn't work. Second of all, yes it works, but not as I want. it iterates through EACH tuple, so it takes `((623, 284), (526, 256), (532, 189))`, then `((504, 166), (323, 175), (276, 219))`, then `((119, 221), (1, 272), (0, 473))` and it stops. I described in my question, how I want it to iterate.

Comment: idk why it decided not to see the loop in first case, but now it works perfectly. thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have points (as a numpy array) and you want angles (*signed* angles), here's a complete solution.

- calculate *vectors*
- use the *cross product*: [image: cross product]

This uses whole-array operations.

*Note* the very valid remark by Yves Daoust in the comments. Acute angles aren't handled properly by this demonstration but they can be with an additional check of the vectors and correction to the angle.

```py
import numpy as np

points = np.array([
 [[623, 284]],
 [[526, 256]],
 [[532, 189]],
 [[504, 166]],
 [[323, 175]],
 [[276, 219]],
 [[119, 221]],
 [[  1, 272]],
 [[  0, 473]],
 [[615, 479]]])
# funny shape because OpenCV. it's a Nx1 vector of 2-channel elements
# fix that up, remove the silly dimension
points.shape = (-1, 2)

# the vectors are differences of coordinates
# a points into the point, b out of the point
a = points - np.roll(points, 1, axis=0)
b = np.roll(a, -1, axis=0) # same but shifted

# we'll need to know the length of those vectors
alengths = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)
blengths = np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)

# we need only the length of the cross product,
# and we work in 2D space anyway (not 3D),
# so the cross product can't result in a vector, just its z-component
crossproducts = np.cross(a, b) / alengths / blengths

angles = np.arcsin(crossproducts)
angles_degrees = angles / np.pi * 180

print("angles in degrees:")
print(angles_degrees)

# this is just for printing/displaying, not useful in code
print("point and angle:")
print(np.hstack([points, angles_degrees.reshape((-1, 1))]))
```

```
angles in degrees:
[-76.24798  79.01601 -55.71665 -42.24728 -40.2652   42.38197 -22.64432 -66.34078 -89.72609 -88.20969]
point and angle:
[[623.      284.      -76.24798]
 [526.      256.       79.01601]
 [532.      189.      -55.71665]
 [504.      166.      -42.24728]
 [323.      175.      -40.2652 ]
 [276.      219.       42.38197]
 [119.      221.      -22.64432]
 [  1.      272.      -66.34078]
 [  0.      473.      -89.72609]
 [615.      479.      -88.20969]]
```

some drawing:

```py
import cv2 as cv

canvas = np.zeros((600, 700, 3)) # floats, range 0..1

cv.polylines(canvas, [points], isClosed=True, color=(1,1,1))

for i,angle in enumerate(angles_degrees):
    cv.circle(canvas, center=tuple(points[i]), radius=5, color=(0,0,1), thickness=cv.FILLED)
    cv.putText(
        canvas,
        f"{angle:+.1f}",
        org=tuple(points[i]),
        fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        fontScale=0.75,
        color=(0,1,1),
        thickness=2)

cv.imshow("canvas", canvas)
cv.waitKey(-1)
cv.destroyWindow("canvas")
```

[image: drawing]

Comment: Good idea to precompute the pairwise differences. But mind that using the cross-product returns an angle over two quadrants only.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz, always remembers this site you should answer OP's question not think about question and answer you like, if you think your answer good create new question and answer yourself.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, you're great and your answer is very good but not for this question

Comment: the question did clearly talk about the goal being angles. how to index into an array and write a loop in python, that's covered in every tutorial. of all the "fancy" answers, I chose mine to show something powerful (numpy and math).  I think it is more valuable to tell people information that they *did not* anticipate, but *would* have asked for, if they knew. in any case, if you were wondering, I didn't downvote anything here.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple

```
for i in range(len(A) - 2):
    getAngle(A[0][i], A[0][i+1], A[0][i+2])
```

---

**Erratum:**

```
for i in range(len(A) - 2):
    getAngle(A[i][0], A[i+1][0], A[i+2][0])
```

Comment: `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Comment: @user16731999: yep, just need to swap the indexings.

Comment: this is the simplest solution, hence should be preferable over the others that add needless complexity

Answer (score 0):

`more_itertools` is a good library for stuff like this:

```
import more_itertools

points = [[623,284], [526, 256], [532, 189], [504, 166], [323, 175], [276, 219], [119, 221], [  1, 272], [  0, 473]]
for triplet in more_itertools.windowed(points, n=3, step=3):
    getAngle(*triplet)
```